# How to assign value to text box control inside the table column in C# coding file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, html-table, webforms

I am creating asp.net web form. in that i am creating dynamic tables in which particular column is numeric text box control.
i don't know how to assign and get values from the text box control.. my coding as follow..

```
                   for (int i = 0; i < my_DataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {

                        HtmlTableRow _Row = new HtmlTableRow();
                        HtmlTableCell Col = new HtmlTableCell();
                        Col.InnerText = my_DataTable.Rows[i]["itmCode"].ToString();
                        _Row.Controls.Add(Col);

                        Col = new HtmlTableCell();
                        _Row.Controls.Add(Col);
                        Col.InnerHtml = "<input type='number' value='0'>";
                        _Row.Controls.Add(Col);

                        my_Table.Rows.Add(_Row);

                    }
```

In a paricular method, i need to assign the value to the text box control also needs to get the value existing value.. so i try follow as below

```
var no_1 =  my_Table.Rows[0].Cells[1].InnerText;
```

If i check the no_1, it has the textbox, but i don't know how to access the current value and assign new value.. 
can anyone help me how to achieve this..

Comment: if the `no_1` is of type `HTMLInputText` then you can set it as:`no_1.Value="SomeValue"` more about it [HtmlInputText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: GridView with TemplateColumns is better options then generating table structure by hand...

Comment: @vikscool, i tried but it returns null.. can you show me , how to convert it to text box and get value from it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you have to keep in mind while working with **Dynamic Controls** is that whenever a `postback` has occurred you will lose the dynamically created controls(*as the postback calls the `Page_load()` event so if you don't have them at the load event they will not be generated and hence will not be displayed.*). So, it is always better to re-render the controls in the load event.

So, in order to get the value of the dynamically assigned controls (either `HTML` or `Asp.net`) here is how i would do that.

First, create a holder which will be used to store the controls in the page either with `runat="server"`(*So, you can access that control in the backend*). In your case, that control is `my_Table`. Then use the `Session/ViewState` to keep a track of all the created dynamic controls which can be used re-render the controls with their values as:

To add a new control in the page it would be like this:

```
var cnt = _findRelated("txtDynamic") + 1; //for all the dynamic text boxes i am using the prefix of txtDynamic just to keep SOC.
var nId = $"txtDynamic-{cnt}";

var _ctrl = new HtmlInputText("Integer")
{
    Name = nId,
    ID = nId,
    //Value="Default Value" //uncomment to assign a default value
};
_ctrl.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
var row = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow();
var newCell = new HtmlTableCell();
newCell.Controls.Add(_ctrl);
row.Cells.Add(newCell);
my_Table.Rows.Add(row);
Session.Add(cnt.ToString(), _ctrl); //here i am using session to manage the controls but you can also use the ViewState
```

In the above code i am using `HtmlInputText` to generate an `<input type="number"></input>` with it's constructor taking the type string more can be read at:[HtmlInputText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_HtmlControls_HtmlInputText__ctor_System_String_).

The `_findRelated()` method is used to get the number of dynamic text controls appended to the `Form`. It is defined as:

```
private int _findRelated(string prefix)
{
    string reqstr = Request.Form.ToString();
    return ((reqstr.Length - reqstr.Replace(prefix, "").Length) / prefix.Length);
}
```

To set the value of the dynamically added control we can do something like this(*if not assigned at the creation*):

```
var cell = my_Table.Rows[_myTable.Rows.Count-1].cells[0]; //here i have assumed it is in the last row and in the first cell you can change the index to be anything.
var txtDynamic = cell.Controls.OfType<HtmlInputText>().FirstOrDefault();//getting the control
txtDynamic.Value = "<Some thing new>"; //setting the value
```

Now, to get the assigned the value:

```
var cell = my_Table.Rows[_myTable.Rows.Count-1].cells[0]; //here i have assumed it is in the last row and in the first cell you can change the index to be anything.
var txtDynamic = cell.Controls.OfType<HtmlInputText>().FirstOrDefault();//getting the control
//now use the .Value property of the control to get the value as:
var nValue = txtDynamic.Value;
```

And as we know the dynamically added controls will be lost on the `postback` event then we can create a method which will use the `controls` stored in the `Session` and re-render them with their values as:

```
private void _renderControls()
{
    try
    {
        if (Session.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < Session.Count; k++)
            {
               if (Session[k] != null)
               {
                    var _ctrl = new HtmlInputText("Integer") //you can make it dynamic to add different types of input control
                    {
                        Name = ((HtmlInputText)Session[k]).ID,
                        ID = ((HtmlInputText)Session[k]).ID,
                        Value = ((HtmlInputText)Session[k]).Value
                    };
                    if (_ctrl != null)
                    {
                        _ctrl.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                        var row = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow();
                        var newCell = new HtmlTableCell();
                        newCell.Controls.Add(_ctrl);
                        row.Cells.Add(newCell);
                        my_Table.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Now, let's modify the `Page_load()` event to call this method on every `postback` as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        _renderDynamic(); // this method will be called if there is an postback event to re-render the dynamic controls
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- This is just a sample(*there can be a lot better approaches out there*).
- I have used `HtmlInputText` with property as `Integer` to create a`input[type="number"]`.